# HTML:"OnMouseOver" implementation

Tags: html, css

I have made some code to display only limited characters while displaying in a html form, I have included this code in a classic asp file. "onmouseover" I have to display whole text. How to achieve this. Suggest some answers please.

Code:

```
<td align="center" class="chaos" width="80%" title="<%=trimtext%>"
```

<%=len(trimtext,50)%>

```
In my code while displaying i`m dislaying only first 25 characters from string variable "trimtext".Onmouseover how can i dispalying complete text.
```

OR:Help me to display only 20 characters,and onmouseover display complete text.Please
suggest some answers.
Thanks

Comment: @nathanhayfield:I don`t know what to try for this.I have not tried anything yet.Please suggest some answers.

Answer (score 2):

ok.... try this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #ddv{
            overflow-x:hidden;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        #ddv:hover{
            overflow-x:visible;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="ddv" style="width: 30px;">
    lskegfoehgfowehfgoqwhfoqwhfgoihqwogfihqwegf
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: John:I didn`t get this.Please be more clear.i dont get where to include this code.

Comment: John Grey:Thanks for the answer.It didnt work for me.Is there a way i can call a function,pass text in it and display data.

Comment: Sorry for the post I used "title" attribute for this.And it worked fine.